# Firebase console no new user created

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am performing user Sign Up with Firebase. For this I am using the "createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)" method to create a new user. Using Chrome DevTools, the debugging console, I find no errors. Still no new user is created in my console.

My HTML code for the elements is the following:

```
<section id="first_part_page">

        <form id="Subscribe_Form">

            <input class="input_box" id="email_input" type="text" placeholder="Email">
            <br>
            <input class="input_box" id="input_password" type="text" placeholder="Password">
            <br>
            <input class="main_button" type="submit" id="submit_form" value="Submit" onclick="subscribeFirebase()"> 
        </form>
    </section>
```

I have included following scripts in my Page.

```
    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <script src="js/firebase_subscribe.js"></script>
```

In the last script, "js/firebase_subscribe.js", I have included the following code:

```
//Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "xxxxxx",
authDomain: "xxxxxx",
databaseURL: "xxxxxx",
projectId: "xxxxxx",
storageBucket: "xxxxxx",
messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
appId: "xxxxxx"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//function that handles the subscribe process 
function subscribeFirebase(){

var user_Email = document.getElementById("email_input").value;
var user_Password = document.getElementById("input_password").value;

console.log(user_Email + user_Password);

//new user does not appear in firebase console 

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_Email, user_Password).catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.
var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;
console.log(errorMessage);
// ...
});    
}
```

I have no error messages, everything seems to work fine. Only nothing shows up in my console. So no new user is created. Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: Can you add a `.then` method to the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method to check if Firebase is actually creating that user? Have you also checked if you have enabled email authentication in the Firebase console?

Comment: Hello Edric, I have enabled email authentication.. How do I add the .then method?

Answer (score 0):

Once try this code. If you don't want to save the details into db the remove the storing part in code.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email1,password).then(function(user) { // it create a new user starting point of create user
            user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() { // it send verification mail to the respective user
             console.log("verification email sent"); 
             var db = firebase.firestore();
               db.collection("Users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({
               FirstName :  Firstname,
               LastName : lastname,
               Email : Email1,
               PhoneNumber : phonum
             }).then(function() {
               alert("Document successfully written!");
               }).catch(function(error){  // for when document is not correctly wrote
                alert("Got an error",error); 
                 });// end of the firestore data

             }).catch(function(error) {// for when verification email is not sent to respective mails
            alert(error.message);
            alert(error.code);
            });// end of verification mail
             }).catch(function(error) // error occur when new user is already registered
             {
               alert(error.message);
               alert(error.code);
             }); //end of create user method
```

Comment: Hi "vijju", please consider explaining what you've done to the code that OP has provided, instead of copying from a snippet.

Comment: I wrote comments explaining  what happens at each line